# School options from dropdown settings in LinkedIn

Tags: php, rest, drop-down-menu

I'm building a POC website that allows a user to essentially fill out a resume form. I noticed in LinkedIn that for the school and business settings, a dropdown appears with useful info. Is there a way that I can use that API for my site that will allow a user to start typing a school name and it will pre-populate based on schools that LinkedIn knows about? This is the same for businesses?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  I am thinking based on you question, you are a little over your head on this  one. 
That does not sound like it an API.
If there is documentation on the API may be you could use it.
Getting the user's keystrokes and populating a text field requires a fair knowledge of JavaScript programming.  
Are you really good at JavaScript programming?
Are you familiar with the onkeypress event?

Anyhow you would need a list of all the relevant schools and make that into a JavaScrip object.

Comment: I was wondering if i could use whatever datasource that is if it were publicly available. Similarly, i used the google api for a drop-down menu of city and state for a location field. 

If there was no way for me to get those option in my website, is there an automated way to grab all the options or something else that im not thinking of? I am new to this as my background is more in devops, infrastructure and cloud. Ive recently been trying to learn how to build web apps because of my background.

Comment: @druffin  I asked you some very specific questions. You need to answer them or I do not know how to respond.  I do not know your skill set.  This all relies on how well you know JavaScript and specifically  if you understand when I say onkeypress event.